# Install Ruby 1.9.3-p374 Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-10.10

After install Ruby 1.9.3-p374 on Ubuntu 10.10 I got error:

```
/opt/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby -v
Segmentation fault
```

For installation I used this instructions https://github.com/postmodern/chruby/wiki/MRI

What I should change in installation instruction or how I can found cause of error?.

Answer (score 1):

I should use parameter "--enable-shared"

```
./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc
```

Good example here: https://gist.github.com/4566200